# Slick slider displaying all images together

Tags: jquery, slider

I am having a strange issue with slick slider.

When the page loads for the first time it displays all the images and after few seconds it normalise the slider.

Is there any way to stop the slider being loaded until all the images + page is loaded.

Ref url -- http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the slider and images are properly styled (with css) without initiating the javascript.

Slick probably adds a css-class which provides the needed css. Simply adding the proper classname to your `<ul>` or `<div>` could help resolve this.

Show me the example if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Let me test it without js.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. What did you exactly do to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs across this, the solution is here: https://trungk18.com/experience/slick-layout-shift/